# Transfer speed to network share drops

Tags: network-share, hp-proliant, file-transfer, network-speed

I have an older HP Proliant ML350 G6 server with 1 x Xeon E5504 (2.0 ghz) and 8 gb ram.

If I copy a large file (over 2 gb) to it from a windows 10 workstation, after about 1.5 gb the transfer speed drops from 112 megabytes per second to somewhere between 15 and 20 megabytes per second.

I also have a Synology DS1815+ on the same network. Copying the same file to the Synology is transferred at about 112 megabytes per second all the way through.

I have tried two different OS on the server, tried 3 different hard drives and the problem is identical in all scenarios.

Any ideas what the issue might be?

Sceendump of transfer speed with drop

[image: Sceendump of transfer speed with drop]

Comment: Hi, QoS unchecked from the server and computer NIC ?

Comment: A cache drive on the server fixed it.. i forgot i was transfering from an ssd to a mechanical drive .. the buffer must have filled up is my guess ..

Comment: Thanks for the update, you can post it as an answer, and mark it answered too after, so it could help other(s) with a trouble like you had.

Comment: Do not put things like 'SOLVED' in the question title or text. If you have solved the problem, please post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cache drive on the server fixed it.. i forgot i was transfering from an ssd to a mechanical drive .. the buffer must have filled up is my guess

Comment: Not to keep bothering you but you can accept your own answer if it solved the original issue!